# How do I receive messages in message queue to list

Tags: arrays, vb.net, list, arraylist, message-queue

I want to show my message in message queue to receive one by one not receive all messages at one time so i desired to keep all messages in array and show them by for each loop but it can't work. It get only one message from all message how do I receive and show them one by one?

```
    Dim lstClient As New List(Of String)

    lstClient.Add(mq.Receive().Body.ToString())
    For Each Message In lstClient
        Label1.Text = mq.Receive.Body.ToString()
        'MessageBox.Show(mq.Receive.Body.ToString())
        Timer1.Interval = 10000
        Timer1.Start()
    Next

    mq.Receive()
    lstClient.Clear()
```

Comment: I don;t think you understand how a `Timer` works.  Get rid of the loop.  The idea is that you something - in your case, display the next message - each time the `Tick` event is raised.  If you use that loop then your just going to show all messages in the few milliseconds it takes to execute and just see the last one.  Just show one message and start the `Timer`, then show the next message on each `Tick`.  When there are no more messages, stop the `Timer`.  Also, set the `Interval` in the designer, not in code.  Only set it in code to change it from the default.

Comment: @jmcilhinney: That should be the solution and not a comment.

Comment: @Christoph, I would only post it as an answer if I was going to write the code.  I leave it to the OP to write the code based on those instructions and post that as an answer themselves.

Comment: @jmcilhinney: I would still post is as an answer, as how you do it, the question appears to be unanswered, but in reality it is answered and clear and it's well possible that within the next years nobody is going to post an example and the question remains (seemingly) unanswered (which is relevant in filtering the questions for only unanswered questions).